# How to use nautilus for sftp over ipv6?

Tags: nautilus, sftp, ipv6

I can use the command below in a terminal to get sftp.

```
sftp -6 username@ipv6address%eth0
```

But when I put in

```
sftp://username@ipv6address/
```

I get an error saying, "unable to access location" "connection failed".
I couldn't find any resources for sftp on ipv6 for nautilus.

Edit 1:

```
shh://username@ipv6address/
```

Also doesn't work

Edit 2:

```
ssh://[ipv6%eth0]/             - No hostname specified
ssh://username@[ipv6%eth0]/    - No hostname specified
ssh://[username@ipv6%eth0]/    - Connection failed
```

Comment: Try with `ssh://username@ipv6address/` (in the text box of Nautilus).

Comment: Did you use 'shh' or 'ssh'?

Comment: My bad, I did use ssh just wrong spelling on the post. Just to be sure I did it again being extra careful.

Comment: Sorry, I have no more tips about ipv6 and Nautilus.

Comment: Thanks for trying, did the typing in ssh work for you?

Comment: `ssh://user@ipv4-address` works for me in Nautilus.

Comment: Same but I want to use ipv6. Also check out my new edit.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70736/discussion-between-ra314-and-sudodus).